# User count for a week

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get a count for week.

For example if i input the date as `'2014-04-06'`.

My output should be

```
weekstart   weekend     weekcount                  
2014-04-06  2014-04-13   7
```

I am using id for count. And created is timestamp.
I have get the answer in terms of weeks upto sysdate.

Mysql query please.

Comment: your question is not clear .. you need to get the datas saved in last week ?

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Datetime is too often poorly SQL standard compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [week()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function of MYSQL like this:

```
mysql> SELECT WEEK('2015-02-20',1);
    -> 8
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/5483)**

Do note that:

```
M   F.day   Range   Week 1 is the first week …
0   Sunday  0-53    with a Sunday in this year
1   Monday  0-53    with more than 3 days this year
2   Sunday  1-53    with a Sunday in this year
3   Monday  1-53    with more than 3 days this year
4   Sunday  0-53    with more than 3 days this year
5   Monday  0-53    with a Monday in this year
6   Sunday  1-53    with more than 3 days this year
7   Monday  1-53    with a Monday in this year

M = Mode
F.day = First day of week
```

Comment: i dont want count using week() function. For example my input is 2015-05-31  i should get count for weeks 201-05-31 to 2015-06-06 and 2015-06-06 to 2015-06-13

Comment: Anyways i got the answer